# PostgreSQL commit on UPDATE increment

Tags: sql, postgresql, hamming-distance

I don't know how to name the title of question right, but it be clear right below. I am new to PostgreSQL and the question can be a bit silly.

I have a table named "hash" what has an "id" (bigint) and "val" - bytea type 100 bits long. Number of records is about 20 millions. I want to know hamming distance distribution (histogram) between all records (or 1-0.1 % of them). I need a table named "hist" what will have "id" - the hamming distance and "num" - number of pairs from "hash", what have the distance equal to its "id". So the table "hist" will have 800 rows with "id" from 0 to 800 (min and max hamming distance between pair of 100 bits is 0 and 800) and the "num" - number of pairs. I made this query to insert values:

```
UPDATE hist SET num=num+1  FROM 
(
    SELECT bit_distance(hash,E'\\xffcfff') AS dist FROM hash 
)
AS sub WHERE id = sub.dist
```

So "bit_distance" - function that takes 2 bytea and returns int. All ok, but the problem is that the "num" in "hist" is 0 or 1. That is bad, because after this transaction (as I thought) the "num" of many columns need to be more than 1. I fink that the problem is that the "SET num=num+1" is saving to row ones at the end of transaction an it will be "1=0+1" (0 is there on the start). So i need somehow to commit the "SET num=num+1" while the query runs.

I tried to put the "SET num=num+1" in FOR loop. That made what I want, but the performance was really slow - 20minutes opposite to 0.8s for my first query (I have "hash" and "hist" tables mounted to ram )

I tried to count the nums for subquery

```
UPDATE hist SET num=num+sub.ds  FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT(dist) as ds from
    (
       SELECT bit_distance(hash,E'\\xffcfff') AS dist FROM hash
    )
    GROUP BY dist
)AS sub 
WHERE id = sub.dist
```

But the query will make seq scan and then sort for all 20m records, that is pretty slow to.

Is there any way to make it faster?

P.S. There are some errors in my sql, because it is posted from my memory. But I hope that they do not prevent to understand the general meaning.

P.P.S I will also be thankful if someone can share a link for a good guide in GIST extension writing by C language (I need to build index by hamming distance).

UPDATED for the ask of @a_horse_with_no_name
For example I have tables:

```
+----------------+      +----------------+
|     hash       |      |      hist      |
+----------------+      +----------------+
| id    val      |      | id    num      |
+----------------+      +----------------+
| 1 ,   E'\\0001'|      | 1,    0        |
| 2 ,   E'\\0001'|      | 2,    0        |
| 3 ,   E'\\0003'|      | 3,    0        |
| 4 ,   E'\\0003'|      | ...            |
| 5 ,   E'\\0003'|      | 16,   0        |    
+----------------+      +----------------+
```

I want to get the [histigram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) for [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) beetwean "has" "val" and for example E'\0000'. The output will be:

```
+----------------+      +----------------+
|     hash       |      |      hist      |
+----------------+      +----------------+
| id    val      |      | id    num      |
+----------------+      +----------------+
| 1 ,   E'\\0001'|      | 1,    2        |
| 2 ,   E'\\0001'|      | 2,    3        |
| 3 ,   E'\\0003'|      | 3,    0        |
| 4 ,   E'\\0003'|      | ...            |
| 5 ,   E'\\0003'|      | 16,   0        |    
+----------------+      +----------------+
```

E'\0001'  hamming distance E'\0000' = 1

E'\0003'  hamming distance E'\0000' = 2

In table "hist" an "id" - is distance and "num" is number of pairs with this distance

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to achieve with this. Please [edit] your question and the `create table` statements for the tables in question, some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: plpgsql is apallingly slow for this sort of thing. I'd write it in a language more suited to heavy computation - use plperl or plpython or pl/v8 or something, or do it outside the db.

Comment: @craig-ringer I don't think that will be helpful too. If external or internal script is used it will need a big bandwidth for returning 20m rows, it will be slow too. I need some kind of streaming poses (if its possible) that will sum numbers of pairs with same distance and insert it to "hist". The `num=num+1` almost do this (in 'stream' ), but it don`t accumulates the number during the query run.